# Prove that Fourier matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, interpolation, fourier-transform

I need to show that the Fourier matrix is invertible using the fact that the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix is given by

$$ det(V_n) = \prod_{s,t=0 \\ s<t}^n (z_t - z_s). $$

It is not clear how I should do that but is it possible to prove it using the fact that it is a unitary matrix and so it is invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The matrix $V$ is invertible if and only if $\det(V) \ne 0$. Take a look at the polynomial
$$ \det(V_n) = \prod_{s,t=0 \\ s<t}^n (z_t - z_s). $$
and try to guess why $z_t - z_s$ is never zero.

Comment: Thanks. Well, since we are considering distinct complex numbers there is no way that product is zero. But how does it relate to $F_n$?

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri, $F_n$ is the Vandermonde matrix for ${\displaystyle \omega =e^{-2\pi i/n}} $

Comment: Yes, I know that. But is this sufficient as a proof. I am basically saying that $F_n$ is $V_n$ with a *particular* choice of $w$ and since $det(V_n)$ is not zero then also $F_n$ is invertible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri, Yes, it is sufficient. As soon as you express your matrix in the Vandermonde form, you can use any implication known for Vandermonde matrices. So, the invertibility comes straightforwardly. Basically, I should correct myself and say that $F_n$ is the Vandermonde matrix for the **powers** $\omega^k$ of ${\displaystyle \omega =e^{-2\pi i/n}}$ from 0 to $n-1$. As soon as they are different, we have invertibility.